# Http 400 Request .net

Tags: c#, .net, http

When I enter a url to system something like `http://localhost:2055/test/5*5*5.html`. It throws http 400 request. What is the reason of that ?

Comment: I cannot find your link.

Comment: 400 Bad Request: The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax

Comment: what version of iis are you using?

Comment: I have no problem with 4+4+4 for example

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in your Windows Event Viewer. It will more than likely be throwing an error due to an invalid character in the path. The invalid character will be the asterisk `*`.

You can allow invalid characters in your paths if you absolutely require it, but it's not recommended and can get very sticky:

See Scott Hanselman's post here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: How can I get rid of these character from the url. HttpUtility.UrlEncode doesnt convert it

Comment: @Ryu, try replace it with %2A

Comment: @Marcus... I think @Ryu's browser will already be converting it to a urlencoded format before IIS gets its hands on the request. IIS then does a single URLDecode() pass, which converts it back to a `*` and then you still get the error. You have to jump through all sorts of hoops to allow it through, if memory serves.

Comment: @Ryu try creating a page which doesn't need any illegal characters in the path. I.e. remove the asterisks and go for `/test/555.html`. Or maybe replace the asterisks with a `x`? So: `/test/5x5x5.html`.